# Stepper-like UI, adaptive to different screen sizes

Tags: flutter, material-ui

My Flutter app contains a form, and I want the first page of the form to include an overview of the form steps, which kind of looks like a stepper:

[image]
My app should work on both mobile and web, so it must be suitable for different screen sizes (in this case, mainly different screen widths as the widget is horizontal).

I've tried to implement it but no matter what, either it caused RenderFlex issues for smaller screens or the UI looked really bad on different sizes (e.g. the lines connecting the circle didn't start/end on the centers of the circles, there was too much spacing, etc.).

Can anyone try to implement such a thing and show me how it can be done / provide implementation tips?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @user1969903 Any implementation suggestions will be welcomed, a code example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 44),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 8,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(3, (final int index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 96,
                        width: 96,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                            BorderSide(
                              width: 4,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Text('${index + 1}')),
                      ),
                      Text('Label ${index + 1}'),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```